# Why does Instagram API return two different user_id values for the same user?

Tags: javascript, php, instagram-api

*Nutshell: PHP implementation gets correct user_id, React.js implementation gets incorrect user_id. Why!?*

I implemented the Instagram Basic Display API OAuth flow in PHP and in Javascript under React.

The flow under PHP works fine - I get a code, I `POST` it using curl to `/oauth/access_token`, I receive a `client_id` and an `access_token`, all fine, subsequent Graph API requests work just fine.

Then I moved to rebuild it in Javascript. Here, when I get a code, and I `POST` it using `fetch` to `/oauth/access_token`, with *the same client_id and client_secret*, and the same authenticating user, essentially the same request, just a different redirect URL (obviously), I receive a token and a **different user_id**, one that does **not** work (it gets a 400 error from Graph API).

Oddly enough, the bad user_id is consistently smaller by 1 than the one that I get with PHP: the good one ends with 93, the bad one ends with 92. If I do the unspeakable and just manually increase the wrong user_id I received, I obtain a valid user_id for which the token works!

So why is Instagram sending me a wrong user_id, and how can I help it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the cause, moments ago, after writing the question and earlier wasting 5 hours on analyzing whatever I could think of.

**The `user_id` is sent as a number larger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, and thus JSON.parse fails to parse it correctly**. Instagram should be encoding the `user_id` field as a string. This API endpoint thus needs to be parsed manually. I "fixed" mine by filtering the results as such:
`text = text.replace(/"user_id":\s*(\d+)/,'"user_id":"$1"')`. Still, encoding such large numbers as "numbers" in JSON is a horrible practice and Instagram should fix their API instead.

Comment: You saved my day ! For my part, I used your filter idea in combination with the axios ```transformResponse``` function like this :
```axios.post(url, data, { transformResponse: (res) => JSON.parse(res.replace(/"user_id":\s*(\d+)/, '"user_id":"$1"')) })```